# why javascript string variables must be initialized before concatenation

Tags: javascript, variables, initialization, concatenation

Why is it that I have to define a javascript string variable before using the concat() method on it?  In the code below the console prints nothing.   But if I initialize the variable string like this **var string = "";** it concatenates like it should and prints the string in the console.  This confuses me because I thought that javascript has automatic type casting, so **var string;** should initialize the variable, then when concat() is used on it, it should automatically change the type to "String" and concatenate?

```
var select = document.getElementById("CK_Expertise");
options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
var string;

for (var i=options.length; i--;){
    if(options[i].selected){
        string = string.concat(options[i].value + "<br/>"); 
        }
}
console.log(string);
```

Thank you
- Chris

Comment: how does one type cast nothing into string? "" is not nothing, its an empty character array

Comment: The type coercion can only happen when you assign something. For the .concat function to even work, the js engine will temporarily create a String object behind the scenes, but it needs to know that it's working with a string type first.

Comment: *"Why is it that I have to define a java string variable..."* Java or JavaScript? They're **completely** different languages.

Comment: As an aside, note that `.concat()` is not generally recommended for use on strings: you can and should concatenate with the `+` or `+=` operators.

Comment: @nnnnnn Why not use concat()?   I can see + is more elegant in terms of number of characters used to do the same task,  but is there any other reason?

Comment: `.concat()` is [quite a lot slower](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join) than `+`. Also because it is not commonly used it makes code that _does_ use it a bit harder to read: most JS programmers would expect to see `+` or `+=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This confuses me because I thought that javascript has automatic type casting, so var string; should initialize the variable, then when concat() is used on it, it should automatically change the type to "String" and concatenate?

`var string` *declares* the variable. It starts out with the value `undefined` (which is not a string). `undefined` doesn't have a method called `concat`, and so `string.concat(...)` fails.

Whereas `var string = ""` declares the variable **and** gives it a string value, `""`. Since that's a string, it has a `concat` method, and so `string.concat(...)` works.

Comment: I understand now.  since in the code snippet I posted I am trying to use the concat() method associated with the String type, and string has no value and undefined type, the method concat() is not called so the string wont be assigned to String type because concat() wont be called.  (basically re-iterating what you said).  Thank you T.J.

Comment: @kiwicomb123: You're welcome! One small thing, though; you said *"...and string has no value and undefined type..."* It does have a value; the value is `undefined`. (Yes, that does seem a bit strange, but it's true. `undefined` is a value just like `""` and `false` and `27` are values.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless a variable has a value, it has no type, and no mehtods. There is automatic typecasting in cases like `5 + "5" -> "55"`, but not in your's.

Comment: So even if a variable is assigned a value after it is declared it doesn't change the type of that variable?

Comment: _"Unless a variable has a value, it has no type"_ - A variable will always have some value, but that value might be `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn It depends on one's definition of "type", and "value".

Comment: @sabof: `undefined` [is a value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9), and it [has a type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.10).

Comment: i think we go by ecmascripts's definition of type http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.1, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8

Comment: @kiwicomb123 in JavaScript values have type, but variables don't. Each time you assign a differnt value, the type changes

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, yeah I know. I just don't think it's important in this context.

Comment: @sabof I think it is of much importance. Your previous comment (@nnnnnn) shows a bit of ignorance as well. -1.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak If more people where capable of processing concepts like "significance in a context" and correctly infer knowledge, the world would be a better place. Sorry.

Comment: @sabof yeah, yeah I know.